# jquery flyout menu background li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Playing around with http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CufonizedFlyOutMenu/
I dropped the fly-in descriptions and now trying to get it to load the extra li with style that would "highlight" the li.current-menu-item.

It sets up an object with:

```
var $moving = $('<li />',{
    class : 'move',
    top   : $selected[0].offsetTop + 'px',
        width : $selected[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
    });
```

Later in the code, it is manipulated with:

```
function moveTo($elem,speed){
    $moving.stop(true).animate({
        top     : $elem[0].offsetTop + 'px',
        width   : $elem[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
    }, speed, 'easeOutExpo');
}
```

It creates the li item I want...but it shows up like this:

```
<li class="move" top="41px" style="width: 73px; "></li>
```

How do I get the top to show up as a style? Everything is mostly working...but upon page load it's not getting the "top" style until everything starts?

I loaded up a http://jsfiddle.net/jq7YQ/26/ but I can't get it to work there at all...sigh...but it does work locally?

I'm a rookie...so I'm probably missing something stupid...or there's a better way to do this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example uses parts of jQuery UI (easing) so you need to include that. 
The site links to 'http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CufonizedFlyOutMenu/jquery.easing.1.3.js' and if you add this as a resource in the Fiddle all should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/jq7YQ/28/ check it out. All I did was add the jQuery easing file (which is included in jQuery UI)

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/jq7YQ/30/) is a example for the 'selected' part of your issue.

Comment: but, how do I get it to highlight li.current-menu-item on the load?

Comment: `$selected.trigger('mouseover');` at the end of the script.

Comment: awesome...thank you...in the spirit of learning...would ya mind explaining why that works?

Comment: Read the docs on jquery.trigger if you stilk dont get it ill explain